# How can I find pairs using python?

Tags: python

Let's say I have data in this format (assume tab delimited)

```
1   10,11,15
2   12
3   12,11
4   10,11
```

How can I iterate through the list and count the most popular pairs of objects in the second column?  Assume that the second column can have an unlimited number of items.

The ideal output would return something like

```
pairs count
10,11 (2)
10,15 (1)
11,15 (1)
11,12 (1)
```

Comment: that doesn't look like a `list`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I think the second column of each row represents a list

Comment: This reminds me of my days when I studied `Data Mining`, to find most commonly occurring pattern.

Answer (score 5):

These both make the assumption that you can get your input into a list of lists:

If you have Python 2.7, try a `Counter` in combination with `itertools`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> l = [[10, 11, 15], [12], [12, 11], [10, 11]]
>>> c = Counter(x for sub in l for x in combinations(sub, 2))
>>> for k, v in c.iteritems():
...   print k, v
...
(10, 15) 1
(11, 15) 1
(10, 11) 2
(12, 11) 1
```

If you have Python < 2.6, you could use a `defaultdict` in combination with `itertools` (a cleaner solution will be provided by one of the gurus I'm sure).

```
In [1]: from collections import defaultdict

In [2]: from itertools import combinations

In [3]: l = [[10, 11, 15], [12], [12, 11], [10, 11]]

In [4]: counts = defaultdict(int)

In [5]: for x in l:
   ...:     for item in combinations(x, 2):
   ...:         counts[item] += 1
   ...:
   ...:

In [6]: for k, v in counts.iteritems():
   ...:     print k, v
   ...:
   ...:
(10, 15) 1
(11, 15) 1
(10, 11) 2
(12, 11) 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [7]: with open("data1.txt") as f:
        lis=[map(int,x.split(",")) for x in f]
   ...:     

In [8]: Counter(chain(*[combinations(x,2) for x in lis]))
Out[8]: Counter({(10, 11): 2, (10, 15): 1, (11, 15): 1, (12, 11): 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `combinations` and a `Counter`.

```
from itertools import combinations
import collections

newinput = []

# Removes the tabs
for line in oldinput:
    newinput.append(line.partition("\t")[2])

# set up the counter
c = collections.Counter()

for line in newinput:
    # Split by comma
    a = line.split(',')
    # make into integers from string
    a = map(int, a)
    # add to counter
    c.update(combinations(a, 2))
```

Then, you end up with a `Counter` that has all of your counts:
`(10,15): 1) etc.